# OCR for matrices

Tags: matrices, math-software

I have a bunch of hand-written notes on matrices that I would like to turn into pretty lectures notes using Latex. But typing matrices is boring and time-consuming, so I was thinking that it would be great if the task was automatized.

**Is there an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) that can convert a hand-written matrix?**

It should be doable,since it is a simpler task than what Latexify does (or it seems to me at least).

Additional information:

1. Free is always better :)
2. The data would be mostly numerical values, and sometimes letters or letters with indices.
3. The final output may not necessarily be directly usable in Latex (format \begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix } or similar) but has to be standard enough so that it can be easily converted so that Latex or other softwares can understand it.
4. If it is necessary that the handwritten document contains only matrices to work properly, it is fine for me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think it is great idea for converting handwriting text to latex form. You can try some free tools like [tensor flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).